# Redirecting a www site to non-www site using web.config

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, azure-web-app-service

I'm a bit new to using IIS and one of the things i'm trying to do is redirecting a www based domain to a non-www based one

The reason is because i have ssl support for the non-www based domain , while the www domain is showing an ssl error

https://example.com works

https://www.example.com throws an ssl error

I'm using web.config as the webserver , but no matter the changes - i cant get the site to redirect itself to non-www

ive tried two ways in `web.config`

```
<rule name="Second_Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.(.*.)(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}" />
</rule>
```

and also

```
 <rule name="Second_Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" />
    </rule>
```

neither works :(

is there something else i can do?

Thanks

Comment: I just checked the second option, it could work on my side. How many rules are you using? Could you update your question with the full rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite rule to remove `www`:

```
<rule name="remove www url part">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.+)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://{C:2}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```